# Unit Test IQueryable

Tags: .net, unit-testing, generics, collections, iqueryable

I am trying to write a unit test for a method which takes an IQueryable collection.

How should I instantiate the collection in my unit test before I pass it to the method for test? This is the default code in my test

```
IQueryable<Item> Items = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
```

And here is what I tried writing

```
IQueryable<Item> Items = new IQueryable<Item>; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
```

Am I making a school boy error?

Comment: Interfaces cannot be instantiated, mock them instead

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, you can use `.AsQueryable()` on any typed collection/list/array, however IMO you ***cannot*** unit test this, as different query providers support different options/methods. You can only integration-test this. Any unit test (especially one using objects) does little or nothing to prove your *system*.

Comment: But this will pass a unit test?? -- IQueryable<Item> Items = new IQueryable<Item>.AsQueryable();

Comment: @suggy1982 no I mean you would create an array/list/whatever with your dummy data and use `theList.AsQueryable()` which will work. However, I repeat: our aim is not merely to "pass tests" - it should be feared towards proving something valuable and meaningful about our system. Since `IQueryable<T>` is so different between implementations, mocking/faking this interface proves almost nothing.

Comment: Example of Integration test  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706864/iqueryable-unit-or-integration-test/38708116#38708116

Comment: @MarcGravell, It may be useful to create unit tests and use mocks  to validate order and parameters of internal calls as shown in

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686286/unit-testing-code-using-iqueryable

Answer (score 3):

IQueryable seems to be an interface ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx ), shouldn't you try to instanciate a class that implements this interface instead (or maybe use a mock object for your test) ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a pattern that let's you test IQueryable responses from a database such as the [Unit of work and repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

The best way to create a mock repository to use in unit testing is with a [memory repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5502130/1343595), but you can also use [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) or any other fake repository library.